# In ruby on rails How to allow users to Create a post only Sunday(one day) rest of the weekday make create post not allow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

we have 7 days in a week but users allow to create a post on only one day which is Sunday,
how can I achieve that. pls need help i am new to rails

in teams/controller

```
class TeamsController < ApplicationController
before_action :find_team_member, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

def index
    @teams = Team.all
end 

def new
    @team = Team.new 
end

 def create
    @team = Team.create(team_params)
    @team.save
    params[:team][:team_employees].each do |emp_id| 
       @team.team_employees.create(employee_id: emp_id) 
    end
    #@team.employee_ids = params[:team][:team_employees]
    redirect_to teams_path
 end

private
  
 def find_tem_member
    @team = Team.find(params[:id])
 end

 def team_params
    params.require(:team).permit(:employee_id,:name,:restaurant_name)
 end
end
```

in teams/view

```
<%= form_with model: @team, local: true do |f| %>
    <div class="field">
    <div class="field">
    <%= f.label "Add Leader"%>
   <%#= f.select :employee_id, Employee.where(is_leader: true).pluck(:name)%>
<%= f.collection_select :employee_id, Employee.where(is_leader: true),:id,:name, include_blank: true %>
<%= f.text_field :name%>
<%= f.text_field :restaurant_name%>
    </div></br>
    <div class="field">
    <%= f.label "Add users to team" %><br />
    <%= f.collection_check_boxes :team_employees, Employee.where(is_leader: false), :id, :name do |b| %>
        <div class="collection-check-box">
          <%= b.check_box %>
          <%= b.label %>
        </div>
     </div>   
  <% end %>
  
  </br>
    <%= f.button :submit%>

  <% end %>
```

in Team/model

```
class Team < ApplicationRecord
has_many :team_employees
has_many :employees, through: :team_employees
belongs_to :employee
end
```

1. we have 7 days in a week but users allow to create a post on only
   one day which is Sunday,  how can I achieve that. pls need help i am new to rails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use plain Ruby to check the current date/time, and halt the request if it's not Sunday. For example, you can use the [`Time#sunday?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.1/Time.html#method-i-sunday-3F) method:

```rb
require "time"

Time.now().sunday?
# => true or false

Time.parse("2022-07-09 11:10 UTC").sunday?
# => false

Time.parse("2022-07-10 11:10 UTC").sunday?
# => true
```

In Rails, you might also want to check the timezone of the user. A certain point in time could be Sunday in some place and Saturday or Monday somewhere else. For example:

```rb
timestamp = 1657494000

Time.at(timestamp, in: "+02:00").sunday?
# => false

Time.at(timestamp, in: "-03:00").sunday?
# => true
```

Rails provides [its own advanced API](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.0.3/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone.html) to represent and work with timezones, but then how to determine the timezone of the current user is up to you. For simplicity, let's assume that you either want to use the server timezone or that you have something in app setup that sets it automatically. Therefore, using Rails' [`Time.zone.now()`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.0.3/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html#method-i-now) should be better than plain Ruby's `Time.now()`, although the returned `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone` instance must be converted to a plain `Time` instance in order to call the `#sunday?` method.

Bringing everything together, your controller's action could include this:

```rb
def create
  current_time = Time.zone.now.time
  unless current_time.sunday?
    flash[:error] = "You can't create a team unless it's Sunday"
    redirect_to teams_path
    return
  end

  @team = Team.create(team_params)
  # ... the rest of your logic
end
```

---

PS: if you invoke `@team = Team.create(team_params)`, that already inserts the record. You don't need to also call `@team.save`.